# Poky image 3.1.2 fails due to gcc-cross-x86_64-9.3.0

Tags: bitbake

Im facing some difficulty on my virtual machine, when I try to build an image documented by [yoctoproject](http://gcc-cross-x86_64-9.3.0-r0%20do_compile:%20oe_runmake%20failed).

I use the command "bitbake core-image-minimal"
The error which occurs looks like:

ERROR: gcc-cross-x86_64-9.3.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: gcc-cross-x86_64-9.3.0-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/debian/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-x86_64/9.3.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.8967' failed with exit code 1:

Is there some issue with my VM ?